# Spark Scala: group by multiple columns with aggregation logic

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, group-by

Given the following DataFrame:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----+------+------+------+
|name|platform|group_id|width|height|     x|     y|
+----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+------+
|   a|  plat_a|       0|500.0|1000.0|250.41|500.01|
|   a|  plat_a|       0|250.0| 500.0|125.75| 250.7|
|   a|  plat_a|       0|300.0| 800.0| 120.0| 111.7|
|   b|  plat_b|       0|500.0|1000.0| 250.5|500.67|
|   b|  plat_b|       1|400.0| 800.0|100.67|200.67|
|   b|  plat_b|       1|800.0|1600.0|201.07|401.07|
+----+--------+--------+-----+------+------+------+
```

I would like to group by name, platform, group_id and count by the following columns logic:

```
//normalizing value to percent with 2 digit precision
new_x = Math.round(x / width * 100.0) / 100.0
new_y = Math.round(y / height * 100.0) / 100.0
```

So the output DataFrame would be:

```
+----+--------+--------+------+------+-----+
|name|platform|group_id| new_x| new_y|count|
+----+--------+---------------+------+-----+
|   a|  plat_a|       0|   0.5|   0.5|    2|
|   a|  plat_a|       0|   0.4|  0.13|    1|
|   b|  plat_b|       0|   0.5|   0.5|    1|
|   b|  plat_b|       1|  0.25|  0.25|    2|
+----+--------+--------+------+------+-----+
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with a straightforward approach ? What have you tried ? (I didn't downvote your question)

Comment: Just take a look at Spark Docs on Aggregate functions section - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be quite straightforward `groupBy` and `count`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("new_x", round($"x" / $"width" * 100.0 ) / 100.0)
  .withColumn("new_y", round($"y" / $"height" * 100.0 ) / 100.0)
  .groupBy("name", "platform", "group_id", "new_x", "new_y")
  .count()
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|name|platform|group_id|new_x|new_y|count|
+----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
|a   |plat_a  |0       |0.5  |0.5  |2    |
|b   |plat_b  |0       |0.5  |0.5  |1    |
|b   |plat_b  |1       |0.25 |0.25 |2    |
|a   |plat_a  |0       |0.4  |0.14 |1    |
+----+--------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
```